QFX10002-36Q FIB/RIB License
We have 2x Juniper QFX10002-36Q i want to know do we need any special license to use 4M FIB and 10M RIB or is it based on honor based like other models?
Also, What about BGP?

Honor-based licensing doesn't mean that you don't need a license. It's just not enforced.

i know this, but i just want to do a few test in my lab then use it in produncational enviroments, so i asked for this reason
